# Parsing this specific JSON from a auto directed url in Android

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to parse the JSON Array from http://inspirontrance.com/app.php but its not working. I believe there could be issues on my code or the url is simply redirecting to another url that defaultHttpClient doesn't supports.

See my code,

Android Parsing Activity Class

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static String url = "http://www.inspirontrance.com/app";

    private static final String TAG_UPLOADS = "uploads";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
    private static final String TAG_UPLOAD_NO = "0";

    JSONArray uploads = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> uploads_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            uploads = json.getJSONArray(TAG_UPLOADS);

            for (int i = 0; i < uploads.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = uploads.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject upload_no = c.getJSONObject(TAG_UPLOAD_NO);
                String name = upload_no.getString(TAG_NAME);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                uploads_list.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, uploads_list,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME },
                new int[] { R.id.name });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

JSON Parser Class

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: first your getJSONFromUrl should perform in a separate thread,but what's happen excactly?do you get any error? I think your code is well done

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Can you post Logcat here?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is stated in your stack trace :

> Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

The corresponding activity seems to be your AndroidJSONParsingActivity which extends ListActivity. A ListActivity performs many things automatically and assume that your layout (in your case `R.layout.main`) contains a ListView with the android.R.id.list.

Check your `main` layout and make sure that you have a ListView like this :

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list" 
    [...]
    />
```